# sorting react dynamic list by value on click

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, dynamic

I am trying to sort this array (`participants`) by `rank`, descending, before render, but am running into issues where added values overwrite following objects in the array.

Here is a sample array and part of the code I'm using, followed by examples of output I'm receiving.

```
const participants= [
    {rank: 15, name: 'Alex'},
    {rank: 5, name: 'Eric'},
    {rank: 16, name: 'Jon'},
    {rank: 20, name: 'Zach'},
]
```

```
renderRows() {
    var context = this;

    const sortedParticipants = [...this.state.participants].sort((a, b) => b.rank - a.rank);
    console.log(sortedParticipants); //confirms sortedParticipants is sorted

    // return  [...this.state.participants].sort((a, b) => b.rank - a.rank).map(function(o, i) { //ALTERNATE RETURN
    return  this.state.participants.map(function(o, i) {
    /* using this.state.sortedParticipants results in a blank screen */
        return (               
            <tr key={'participants-' + i}>
                <td>
                    <input
                        id='rank'
                        type='text'
                        value={o.rank}
                        onChange={context.handleParticipantChanged.bind(context, i)}
                    />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input
                        id='name'
                        type='text'
                        value={o.name}
                        onChange={context.handleParticipantChanged.bind(context, i)}
                    />
                </td>                                     
                <td> 
                    <button onClick={context.handleParticipantDeleted.bind(context, i)}> 
                        Delete 
                    </button>
                </td>                    
            </tr>
        );
    });
}
```

When I run it, the `console.log` confirms `sortedParticipants` is sorted as desired, but using `return  this.state.sortedParticipants.map(function(o, i) {` gives a blank screen.
If I run with the alternate return it almost works fine, but if any variable is changed, it pushes the old value to the next corresponding key. For example, the first three objects in the array will output;

```
0: Object { rank: "16", name: "Jon" }​
1: Object { rank: "15", name: "Alex" }​
2: Object { rank: "5", name: "Eric" }
```

But if you try to change the first object to `20, Zach` in the table inputs, object 0 overwrites object 1.

```
0: "Zach"​
1: Object { rank: "16", name: "Jon" }​
2: Object { rank: "5", name: "Eric" }
```

Further, if you try to enter `15, Alex` back into object 1, the current data overwrites the next object.

```
0: "Zach"​
1: "Alex"​
2: Object { rank: "16", name: "Jon" }
```

Finally, if we enter a 5th participant (`18, Jeff`), this happens;

```
0: "Zach"​
1: "Alex"​
2: Object { rank: "18", name: "Jeff" }​
3: Object { rank: "16", name: "Jon" }
```

I do not understand why this is happening and have been unable to find any literature that helps just yet. Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer!

**EDIT:**
Here is `handleParticipantChanged`;

```
handleParticipantChanged(i, event) {        
        var participants = this.state.participants;
        participants[i] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            participants: participants
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the `context.handleParticipantChanged` function?

Answer (score 0):

**sortedParticipants**

Addressing the first part of your question, `sortedParticipants` looks right while `this.state.sortedParticipants` does not, since you aren't storing the output of the `.sort` method into that state value. Either store it there, or maybe preferably, just reference the variable name without the `this.state.` prefix.

```
const sortedParticipants = [...this.state.participants].sort((a, b) => b.rank - a.rank);
console.log(sortedParticipants); //confirms sortedParticipants is sorted
```

The above makes sense, as you are logging the resulting, sorted participants array.

```
return  this.state.participants.map(function(o, i) {
/* using this.state.sortedParticipants results in a blank screen */
```

You get a blank screen here since you never store the `sortedParticipants` array into the `this.state` object. It only exists as the local variable, so you can reference it as just `sortedParticipants` rather than `this.state.sortedParticipants` (or store the result in state, but that wouldn't make sense here).

**handleParticipantChanged**

You are seeing that the value is being replaced by just the name, because you are setting the entire value to the new string rather than just the name property.

Notice the difference between...

```
participants[0] = "hello";
// [ "hello", { rank: 10, name: "Jesse" }, { rank: 11, name: "Emily" } ]
```

...and this...

```
participants[0].name = "hello";
// [ { rank: 9, name: "hello" }, { rank: 10, name: "Jesse" }, ... ]
```

You want to replace the *name* property of the participant at that index, not the entire value at that index. This is a pretty easy fix:

```
// change this
participants[i] = event.target.value;

// to this
participants[i].name = event.target.value;
```

Comment: Hi! I have added `handleParticipantChanged` as an edit. At which location do you mean to reference without `this.state`? I tried referencing with and without `this.state` at various points, but had no luck in producing the desired results.

Comment: Edited to address handleParticipantChanged and the this.state confusion